# After the node goes offline, data is still being written to the offline node

Tags: database, cnosdb

I am trying the node offline function here. But I encountered a problem during the process：After the node goes offline, data is still being written to the offline node.

the step as follow:

1. start cluster 3m2d;
2. wait a minute ,check usage_schema data which node stored the vnode;
3. removenode the nodeid;
4. wait a minute;Check whether the usage_schema data has increased, and check whether another node has a new vnode.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Can you help explain it?